# problemas con los store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me piden que haga un SP que me haga esta consulta:

> <<En qué local o locales el producto “Pan Integral” de marca “La Espiga” de 500 gramos está más barato.>>

```
AS
Begin
select co.nombreComercio, MIN(pc.idPrecio)
from precio pc
join comercio co on co.idComercio = pc.idComercio
join presentacion ps on ps.idPresentacion = 
pc.idPresentacion
join producto pr on ps.idProducto = pr.idProducto
join marca ma on pr.idCategoria = pr.idMarca
where ps.capacidad='500 gramos' and pr.nombre ='pan 
integral' and ma.Marca = 'La Espiga'
group by co.nombreComercio

end
```

Esta es la consulta que hice yo.... pero no responde a lo que me pidieron.

Comment: qué error te sale?

Comment: porque decis que no lo responde?

Comment: para mi, muchas de esas tablas tienen una relacion muchos a muchos, y seguro no se deberian consultar asi... puede ser?

Comment: "Debería devolver los comercios en donde el producto es más barato.
En este caso devuelve todos los comercios, con un precio min (pero como cada comercio tiene un precio para cada producto simplemente devuelve el precio)

La capacidad y la unidad de medida están en campos distintos."
este es el error.....

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon cuál es el comportamiento esperado y el obtenido (no solo en los comentarios). ¿Qué problema _específico_ estás teniendo? Además, pon un título relevante para la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas con tu código. En primer lugar estás usando el ID del precio en vez de su valor real. Otro problema es que estás obteniendo solo el precio mínimo de cada comercio. Lo que necesitas es usar `TOP` con su opción `WITH TIES` para que traiga varias filas si tienen el mismo valor.

Quedaría algo así.

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
     co.nombreComercio
    ,pc.Precio --Sin ID
FROM precio       pc
JOIN comercio     co ON pc.idComercio     = co.idComercio
JOIN presentacion ps ON pc.idPresentacion = ps.idPresentacion
JOIN producto     pr ON ps.idProducto     = pr.idProducto
JOIN marca        ma ON pr.idCategoria    = ma.idMarca
WHERE ps.capacidad = '500 gramos' 
AND   pr.nombre    = 'pan integral' 
AND   ma.Marca     = 'La Espiga'
ORDER BY pc.Precio; --Sin ID
```

Nota también de que es mucho más fácil leer el código si le das un poco de formato. Así pude identificar que tu JOIN con marca estaba incorrecto porque comparaba 2 columnas de la tabla marca y el nombre del producto estaba dividido por un salto de línea.